# What causes the differing behavior in processing list parameters and dictionary parameters passed to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, methods

When trying to use a function call to modify the value of a variable in the calling function, I observed the following difference in behavior when passing a list and set as function parameters.

```py
#Passing list as parameter
def fun(a):
    a = a.append(13)

a = [12]
print(a)
fun(a)
print(a)

#Output
[12]
[12, 13]
```

```py
#Passing set as a parameter
def fun(a):
    a = a.union({13})

a = {12}
print(a)
fun(a)
print(a)

#Output
{12}
{12}
```

My question is, **why is the changes from the function carried over to the calling function when using a list but not when using set even though they are both of mutable data types?**

Comment: `a.append` alters the list `a`. `a.union` creates a new set but doesn't modify the original. They are not equivalent.

Comment: Just because a type is mutable, doesn't mean that every method of that type mutates its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operations you are comparing are not equivalent.

`alist.append` alters the list at `alist` (and returns `None`).
`aset.union` creates a new set but doesn't modify the original.

If you did `aset.add(13)` that would be the set equivalent of `alist.append(13)` (adding a new element to an existing collection).
If you did `alist = alist + [13]` that would be the list equivalent of `aset = aset.union({13})` (creating a new collection containing extra elements).